# Cannot access protected URL using postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth

I am having trouble with a Spring Boot OAuth2 project. I created my application as a client and started the server. I am able to access the protected URLs using my browser but cannot do the same using Postman (even after creating an OAuth2.0 Token and sending it as an Authorization header). While trying it with Postman it always returns an HTML document of the google sign in page.
I'm using the

```
oauth2-client
```

dependency for my application.

I tried adding a custom filter but it's not working. I even tried using the JWT token instead of the access_token (opaque token) issued but that didn't work either.
When I'm trying to access the protected URLs using the browser it is able to get information of the signed in user and is returning the expected value.

Edit: I am using Google as the authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

Requests between a web-browser and a Spring OAuth2 **client** are not OAuth2. By default, it is secured with sessions, not `Bearer` `Authorization` header.

Postman is primarily a REST client, not a web browser. It is intended to test REST APIs (`@RestController` or `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody`) which are **resource-servers**, not clients.

It is possible for an app to be both a resource-server (REST API) and a client (`@Controller` with methods returning the name of Thymeleaf templates or using WebClient to query other OAuth2 web-services), but you'll have to configure two separate SecurityFilterChains segregated with `securityMatcher`:

- a "client" one with sessions, CSRF protection and oauth2Login for your Thymeleaf pages (or JSF or any other server-side rendering framework)
- a "resource-server" one with JWT decoder or introspection and likely disabled sessions and CSRF.

You can refer to [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote for instructions to configure a resource-server (there is even a tutorial with a Spring app being both resource-server and client)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials link. I forgot to mention that I am using **Google** as the Authentication provider. I added the Google client ID and secret key and changed the _jwt-issuer-uri_ and _jwk-set-uri_ in your application. What other changes do I have to bring to redirect to google for authentication? I am new to this concept so can you help me out?

Comment: Are you sure that the access tokens you get from Google are JWTs? Check it on https://jwt.io. For opaque tokens, introspection should be used instead of JWT decoder.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, Google authorization-servers are "reserved" to Google resource-servers. Use an authorization-server of your own with "social login" in front of it. Many OIDC authorization-server do it out of the box (Keycloak, Auth0, Amazon Cognito,...)

Comment: Yeah, actually it generates opaque token as well as JWT. So, using my own authorization-server is the way to do it? Can you suggest any reference material for learning Keycloak?

Comment: Their getting started guide is quite good. You can also have a look at my tutorials. For production environments, you should also consider OIDC SaaS offers like Auth0, Cognito, etc., it could save you quite some hassle

Comment: Thanks. Cam you suggest where to look for the introspection uri of google?

Comment: I have not found a standard introspection endpoint. I fear you'll have to write your own introspector using the user-info endpoint. I personally don't use introspection for performance reasons (this is way too inefficient and slow)